# Classic ASP in the Feature View

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp-classic

Am I missing something here? I am trying to configure Classic ASP on Windows 2008 Server SP1 and all the documentation points to an ASP option in the features view of IIS7.

I've got IIS7 open, Classic ASP is enabled but for the life of me I can't find a ASP option in the Features view.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have ASP configured as a role on the server?  Go to Server Manager, Roles and verify that Application Development -> ASP is installed.

Comment: Yes. ASP == Installed

Answer (score 1):

Installed Windows 2008 SP 2 and now ASP Feature is showing up.